# Why does std::round(sin(pi/6)) not equal 1?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

The cppreference documentation states that [std::round](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) will specifically round away from zero in "halfway cases." While this is true with the literal `0.5`, it's not true with `std::sin(pi/6)`. I thought this might be a floating point error, so I printed the value but it's exactly `0.5`. After inspecting the binary representation however, I can see that they are indeed represented differently. I've provided the code I used to make these inspections below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    double const pi = std::acos(-1);
    double const a = std::sin(pi/6);
    double const b = 0.5;

    std::cout << "round(" << a << ") = " << std::round(a) << "\n";

    auto pa = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&a);
    auto pb = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&b);

    std::cout << "a = 0x";
    for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(double); ++i) {
        printf("%02x", pa[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "\nb = 0x";
    for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(double); ++i) {
        printf("%02x", pb[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

```
round(0.5) = 0
round(0.5) = 1
a = 0xffffffffffffdf3f
b = 0x000000000000e03f
```

So my question is this rounding behavior a part of the c++ specification or is this a bug? And in any case, is there some general way that I can "correct" the representation of the value returned by `sin`? I'm not sure what format it's in because based off what I know of IEEE-754, it looks like it should be NaN. Although from what I understand, c++ doesn't guarantee IEEE-754 floating point representation?

Comment: If you print some more decimal places with `std::setprecision(17)` you will see that `a` is actually 0.49999999999999994, output also rounds values.

Comment: Those are not NaN, but you can check with [`isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan). Are you aware of [`std::hexfloat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)?

Comment: `pi` is actually an irrational value, so the calculated value of `pi/6` in floating point - which has a finite precision - will always be an approximation. That means the result of calculating `sin(pi/6)` will also be an approximation, not necessarily equal to `0.5`.  Whether the calculated value is greater than, equal to, or less than `0.5` is implementation (compiler and host system) specific. If `std::round(sin(pi/6))` produces a value of zero it indicates, for your implementation, that the actual value is less than `0.5`. Printing the value to a greater precision would confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not printing the value with enough significant digits.  When I increase precision with `std::setprecision(20)`, I get: `round(0.49999999999999994449) = 0`.

You can see this for yourself by either changing the code or entering `3fdfffffffffffff` into the bottom Hexadecimal field of this online calculator: https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point

Answer (score 1):

The representation looks like NaN because you're reading it backwards. x86/x64 have little-endian floating point numbers. So you should read that it from high to low address, yielding `0x3fdfffff...`, which is of course slightly less than 0.5.